# NSTable row click event

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mac

I am working on a Xamarin Mac application and am currently creating a newsfeed list.

What I would like to have is that when the user click on one of the row I do some stuff (open up a browser and show the full story).

Here is how my custom cell (row) looks like.

```
public class CustomLatestNewsCell : NSView
{
    public NSText Title;
    public NSText Date;
    public NSText Details;


    public CustomLatestNewsCell()
    {
        Title = new NSText();
        Title.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 120, 300, 70);
        Title.TextColor = NSColor.FromSrgb((nfloat)0.207, (nfloat)0.576, (nfloat)0.639, (nfloat)1);
        Title.Font = NSFont.UserFontOfSize(20);
        Title.Editable = false;
        Title.Selectable = false;
        this.AddSubview(Title);

        Date = new NSText();
        Date.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 25, 300, 30);
        Date.TextColor = NSColor.FromSrgb((nfloat)0.702, (nfloat)0.702, (nfloat)0.702, (nfloat)1);
        Date.Editable = false;
        Date.Selectable = false;
        this.AddSubview(Date);

        Details = new NSText();
        Details.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(310, 120, 550, 32);
        Details.TextColor = NSColor.FromSrgb((nfloat)0.5, (nfloat)0.5, (nfloat)0.5, (nfloat)1);
        Details.Editable = false;
        Details.Selectable = false;
        this.AddSubview(Details);

        this.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, 850, 150);
    }
}
```

I have tried a lot of things but there doesn't seem to be a click/activated/somethingElse function which will trigger when I click on anything in the cell. The only thing that works is

```
public override void SelectionIsChanging(NSNotification notification)
{
    var row = (NSTableView)notification.Object;
    var selectedRow = row.SelectedRow;
    if(selectedRow < 0)
        return;

    var selectedFeed = feed[(int)selectedRow];
    row.DeselectAll(row);

    NSWorkspace ws = new NSWorkspace();
    NSError error = new NSError();
    ws.OpenURL(new NSUrl(selectedFeed.Url),
            NSWorkspaceLaunchOptions.AllowingClassicStartup,
            new NSDictionary(),
            out error);
}
```

but in this case the user has to click on some "empty" parts of the row. Is there a way that I catch a click on any of the parts in the cell and then trigger the action?

I am quite new to Mac development so I am quite lost at the moment