# NSTable cell click event in Xamarin.mac

Tags: onclick, nstableview, xamarin.mac

After having searched a lot without success for a way to manage the click event on a NSTable delegate in *Xamarin.mac*, for instance the following thread without answers after two years:
[NSTable row click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29920444/nstable-row-click-event)
I made an override of *ShouldSelectRow* method, always returning *false* to be called more then once, in order to manage click event row and column, but preventing me to use selection!
I am new in Xamarin. I used the Main.storyboard in Visual Studio Professional to call XCode where I settled the NSTable definition.
Thanks for help.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by 'managing' the click event?

Comment: Depending on the column, I want to refresh the table with a query based on the cell value, or open a new panel for setting properties for the row, etc...

Comment: Really the same problem is to intercept the 'focus' event in a simple NSTextField: I have  'dateFrom' and 'dateTo' fields and would like to popup a NSDatepicker when clicking into or reaching them by Tab key.